# How does one install opam with conda for Mac/apple/os-x?

Tags: macos, anaconda, conda, miniconda, opam

I discovered that one can install much more than python stuff in conda. I am instlaling opam with conda for ubuntu with:

```
conda install -c conda-forge opam
```

and wanted to do it for my mac. Got some issues.

```
(iit_synthesis) brandomiranda~/iit-term-synthesis ❯ conda install -c conda-forge opam
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - opam

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

does anyone know how to resolve them or install opam with a mac?

Comment: check https://github.com/conda-forge/opam-feedstock/issues/1 perhaps this will add it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The Conda Forge [feedstock for `opam`](https://github.com/conda-forge/opam-feedstock) is only configured to build for **linux-64** platform. Consider opening [an Issue](https://github.com/conda-forge/opam-feedstock/issues) to request additional platform support for Conda.

Otherwise, there are [binary distribution options](https://opam.ocaml.org/doc/Install.html#Binary-distribution) for MacOS.

Comment: like this? https://github.com/conda-forge/opam-feedstock/issues/1

Comment: Sure, but it might be more well-received as a request to include a build for **osx-64** in the feedstock. There is nothing mystical about why you can't install it - the feedstock maintainers simply aren't building it at the moment.