# Why does command substitution with a command in front e.g. eval interprets the string as literal zsh commands to execute?

Tags: zsh, eval, command-substitution

I was going through this [What is the use of eval `opam config env` or eval $(opam env) and their difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30155960/what-is-the-use-of-eval-opam-config-env-or-eval-opam-env-and-their-differen) and notice something funny. I understand command subtitution is used to nest commands in zsh by evaluating a zsh cmd in a subshell and then giving it to the output as input to the command in front e.g.

```
eval $(cmd)
```

runs cmd replaces `$(cmd)` and gives it to the command `eval`. But when eval is not there is actually tries to interpret at string literal commands which to me is odd because if I gave that literal string to the termianl it would evaluate it just fine. e.g.

```
(iit_synthesis) brandomiranda~ ❯ $(echo v=1)
zsh: command not found: v=1
(iit_synthesis) brandomiranda~ ❯ v=1
(iit_synthesis) brandomiranda~ ❯ echo $v
1
```

interprets `v=1` as a command to run but if I would have typed `v=1` it would have evaluated and set the variable just fine. So what is the implicit command `$(echo v=1)` is giving to?

e.g. if I added eval in this case it would have worked which is strange to me. I would have expected that if `$(echo v=1)` just returns the string `v=1` which is what we are echoing and then runs it in the terminal.

Note, eval at the front does work:

```
(iit_synthesis) brandomiranda~ ❯ echo vv=2
vv=2
(iit_synthesis) brandomiranda~ ❯ $(echo vv=2)
zsh: command not found: vv=2
(iit_synthesis) brandomiranda~ ❯ eval $(echo vv=2)
(iit_synthesis) brandomiranda~ ❯ echo $vv
2
```

related:

- [What is the use of eval `opam config env` or eval $(opam env) and their difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30155960/what-is-the-use-of-eval-opam-config-env-or-eval-opam-env-and-their-differen?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [What does eval $(opam env) do, does it activate a opam environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72522412/what-does-eval-opam-env-do-does-it-activate-a-opam-environment?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 2):

You fell victim to the difference between a command and a command line.

Think about the command line

```
v=1 foo bar
```

This command line (or: statement, if you prefer this word) would run the command `foo` in an environment, which has the variable `v` assigned (in addition to the environment variables of the parent process).

Now imagine you have in your PATH an executable file named `v=1` (which is possible, because nothing forbids you to use an equal sign inside a file name). If you wanted to execute this file, you can not simply write

```
v=1 x y
```

because this would run the command `x` and not `v=1`. Instead you have to write

```
'v=1' x y
```

or

```
command v=1 x y
```

or, if you prefer, using parameter expansion

```
cmd='v=1'
$cmd x y
```

All three variants tell the parser, that the command to be executed, is really the file `v=1`.

In the example from your question, you wrote

```
$(echo v=1)
```

which means that you first produce `v=1` on standard output, and by command substitution run it as command. This command substitiution is similar to  my previous example (where I used `$cmd` to do parameter expansion).

OTOH, if you would do a

```
eval $(echo v=1)
```

the output (`v=1`) is not executed as **command**, but as a full **command line**, i.e. as if you just had typed

```
v=1
```

on the command line, and it is parsed according to the zsh rules of parsing a command line. Therefore, `v=1` is interpreted as variable assignment, and not as command.